# How to pass a json dictionary as part of url?

Tags: json, url

I want to deeplink a url into my ios app and i want to pass a dictionary like

```
[{"id": "fef", "hp": 1000},{"id": "afe"}]
```

I have tried

```
appname://command?p1=2&p2=[{"id": "fef", "hp": 1000},{"id": "afe"}]
```

in my iphone's safari but it treated this as i was googling it. do i have to escape something for the dictionary?

Comment: You can use something like this, to pass the data, ( as any other URL usualy do) URL?id=2489&user=tom&hp=1000

Comment: You can do it this way, but you have to make sure that every key/value components are url encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must *urlencode* your json payload:

```
appname://command?p1=2&p2=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%20%22fef%22%2C%20%22hp%22%3A%201000%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%20%22afe%22%7D%5D
```

instead of

```
appname://command?p1=2&p2=[{"id": "fef", "hp": 1000},{"id": "afe"}]
```

Online url encoder: http://www.urlencoder.org/